# PostgreSQL and Hibernate java.io.IOException: Tried to send an out-of-range integer as a 2-byte value

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, exception, ioexception

I have hibernate query:

```
getSession()                     
        .createQuery("from Entity where id in :ids") 
        .setParameterList("ids", ids)
        .list();
```

where ids is Collection ids, that can contain a lot of ids.
Currently I got exception when collection is very large:
 java.io.IOException: Tried to send an out-of-range integer as a 2-byte value
I heard that postgre has some problem with it. But I can't find the solution how to rewrite it on hql.

Comment: have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 63):

The exception occurs because of PostgreSQL's limit of 32767 bind variables per statement. 
As a possible workaround try to split your large query into smaller ones.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, it has saved me in a production application ! Thanks for your science @andrey-dolgikh.

Comment: related issue on GitHub https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/1311

Answer (score 1):

In newer PostgreSQL driver **42.4.0** you can now pass up to 65,535 records.

> fix: queries with up to 65535 (inclusive) parameters are supported now (previous limit was 32767) PR #2525, [Issue #1311](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/1311#issuecomment-1143805011)

Source: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/changelogs/2022-06-09-42.4.0-release/

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want split your large query into smaller ones, you may use JDBC: ResultSet executeQuery()

Answer (score -7):

Try adding parenthesis around `:ids`, i.e.:

```
"from Entity where id in (:ids)"
```

Comment: it does not matter. Exception the same

Comment: then try executeUpdate();

Comment: you don't know what saying, Do you know anything about work with db?

Comment: i'm just traying to help you :)

Comment: Thanks. I found that it is limits of postgreSQL

Comment: great, happy for you :)

Comment: @РоманБондаренко would you mind linking to the documentation explaining those limits? I'm running into the same error